# Hiding folder in URL with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a WordPress installation on the following URL.

`www.example.com/wordpress/*`

How can I configure my `.htaccess` files so that when the user navigates to:

`www.example.com`   it loads  `www.example.com/wordpress/*` but does not display the `/wordpress`  directory.

Can you please explain what the code actually does, thanks.

Comment: This question has been answered about 6593765846239 times alone here on SO. None of all those answers helped? _Why not_?

Comment: I know,  thats why I posted the question, I have looked at all of the answers and none of the explain what the code is doing, they are just posting code